# how to get C type definition string from ctypes object?

Tags: python, c, ctypes, cffi

I want a generic function that can cast a ctypes object to a cffi object.
It might looks like below

```
def ctypestocffi(ctypes_obj):
    return ffi.cast(get_type_definition(ctypes_obj), ctypes_obj)

get_type_definition(ctypes.c_int)=='int'
get_type_definition(ctypes.c_int*10)=='int[10]' #or 'int[]'
```

I've thought that ctypes itself should have that kind of function, but as far as I know it doesn't. The function needs to work well with structures, pointers and any general c type object.

Does anyone know the function I'm looking for? Or is there any reason that explains why this kind of functions is not implemented in ctypes?

Comment: I guess noone really needed it. [Here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) are the fundamental types. I guess you could do some string processing based on `type(ctypes_obj)` output, but I don't understand the relevance.

Comment: I need it because I'm trying to use numpy and inlined c code using cffi in a single source file. If there isn't, I need to write codes to cast numpy objects(which internally use ctypes) to cffi one by one.